# ParseError Not Being Caught With Except

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, parse-error

I'm newish to coding and I've ran into a problem that I haven't been able to find a solution to.

I have some code that prompts the user to pick a directory and an XML file that it will parse and say whether the XML file is well-formed or not.

However, when the XML is malformed, I get an error and the program stops.

What I expect to happen is that the except will catch the parse error.

When I'm debugging, I can continue past the error and the rest of the code executes.

Here is the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ParseError
mismatched tag: line 306, column 14
  File "C:\Users\user\project\SimpleXMLParseExcept.py", line 10, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 306, column 14
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

directory = input("Enter the directory path: ")
filename = input("Enter the file name in the directory: ")

filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)

try:
    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    print(f"{filename} is a well-formed XML.")
except ET.ParseError as e:
    print(f"{filename} is not a well-formed XML: {e}")
    # Add a print statement to see if the exception is being caught
    print("Exception caught by the try-except block.")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What is the content of your XML file?

Comment: Try accepting all exceptions, and print the exception. My guess would be that the `filepath` is incorrect

Comment: This smells like something where you’re running the wrong version of your code.  Make extra sure that the file in the error message has been saved and has the content you posted (and is the same file you’re running in your debugger).

Comment: The content of the XML file is an obscure .px file used for Niagara BAS graphics.
I have purposefully malformed it, removed a tag, to test whether it will catch the malformation. If I give it a good .px file, it says it passes and if I give it a malformed file it stops with an error when I debug.

I'm running this is VSC with a Python Version of 3.10.4

I tried:

Exception as e:  # Catch all exceptions
    print(f"{filename} is not a well-formed XML: {e}")
    input("Press Enter to continue past the error...")

Comment: Your code works as expected with python 3.11.2.